# Android Game States Change when paused

Tags: android, surfaceview

In a semi traditional fashion,  I have a single activity game (MainActivity) with a single surface view (MainSurface).  I set up two "game states" that render themselves to the surface view canvas (SplashState and ModelState).

When the application starts the surface view hands itself over to the splash state to so it can draw itself to the screen like this.

```
SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                initInput();
                if(currentState == null){
                    setCurrentState(new SplashState());
                }
                initApp();
            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int         width, int height) {

            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                pauseApp();
            }
        });

private void pauseApp(){
        running = false;
        while(appThread.isAlive()){
            try{
                appThread.join();
                break;
            } catch (InterruptedException e){

            }
        }
    }
```

When the user touches the splash screen, it calls to the SurfaceView to change the state to the ModelState (which is the primary state of the application) with this

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(MotionEvent e, int scaledX, int scaledY) {
        setCurrentState(new ModelState());
        return false;
   }
```

All of this works great.  But when I let my device sleep, or use another application then open my app back up, sometimes I get the ModelState, and sometimes I get the SplashState.  Can anyone explain why?  I feel like there is more I should be doing to save the current state of the application when it pauses and resumes so it is sure to start back in the same spot.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the reason for the behavior has to do with the way SurfaceView works.  It's lifecycle is slightly independent of the usual Activity lifecycle.

The phenomenon is discussed in [an appendix to the Graphics Architecture](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#activity) doc.  In short, the system attempts to avoid destroying and re-creating the surface.  If you rotate the device, you get pause/resume and destroy/create.  If you just put the device to sleep and wake it up, and the lock screen doesn't force a rotation change, you will get pause/resume but no destroy/create.

The trick is to manage your rendering thread and resource allocation (notably stuff like opening and closing a Camera) in a way that fits with the dueling lifecycles.

> There are two basic approaches: (1) start/stop the thread on Activity
>   start/stop; (2) start/stop the thread on Surface create/destroy.

The doc goes on to explain what each of those means, and when other actions must be taken in relation.  Examples of both approaches can be found in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika); the "texture from camera" activity uses #1, while the "hardware scaler exerciser" activity uses #2.

Coming back around to your code, you're calling `pauseApp()` from `surfaceDestroyed()`.  Since there's no guarantee that the surface will be destroyed, your `pauseApp()` code may not run when the app is paused.  Add some logging to the various state-change functions and watch them fire (or not) in logcat as you navigate the device.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking to save which state the user was seeing (Model or Splash), you can override onPause and onResume to save and retrieve the state. OnPause and onResume are the only two methods guaranteed to be called when an app goes into the background, so saveInstanceState and restoreInstanceState may not work for you.

Try saving which state the user was in using the SharedPreferences object. Here is an example:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(KEY_SHARED_PREFERENCES, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor sharedPreferencesEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    sharedPreferencesEditor.putString(STATE_KEY, currentState);
    sharedPreferencesEditor.commit();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    sharedPreferences.getString(MODEL_KEY, null)
}
```